# Pass Data between two different component in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

i have two component

- Sidebar Component
- dashboard Component

i am updating something in dashboard component and i want things should automatically update on sidebar menu.

How to achive it kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `ngrx/store` for this or if you'd like to not add this dependency, you can create a common service which will provide you the communication channel between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by creating a service and subject variable. You have to subscribe to the Subject in sidebar menu using a key. And in dashboard you will set the data that needs to be passed using the same key. I hope it helps. Enjoy coding :)